# Check for the result of a query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

To check if the executed query was successful, in PHP all you have to do is

```
$Result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM myTable');
```

& check if 'Result' is false.

My Question is does .NET have any such simple functionality to check if the executed query 
was successful?

I don't want check the result was null, because if it's an insert statement then also the result will be null.

from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php)

**mssql_query**

```
Returns a MS SQL result resource on success, TRUE if no rows were returned, or FALSE on error.
```

Comment: The result of insert statements is null...?

Comment: How do you find out what the error is if the return is false?

Comment: there is a **mysql_error** function google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what other people said (and assuming you are using ADO.NET), for non-SELECT queries you can check the result of the `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`. This gives you the number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

This way you can, for example, check whether the WHERE clause in your UPDATE or DELETE "identified" the correct number of rows.

Comment: Its pathetic.don't you think ?.I mean all PHP requires is check if 'Result' is false.In .net you have to use try cache.I mean if I have 10 separate queries I have to use 1 separate try cache statements.If Microsoft wasn't backing .NET, I doubt anyone will use it at all.I mean its not secure as JAVA nor easy as PHP neither beautiful as python.

Comment: @Jibin No I don't think it is pathetic. ADO.NET is handling errors exactly as it should - errors are represented as exceptions and non-errors are not. BTW, you don't generally have to have separate try..catch blocks for each statement unless you are using exception handling in a very unusual way. "Exceptions", after all, are supposed to be "exceptional" and it is rare to have more than few try..catch blocks for the whole program (and usually far above the level of the data access layer). You do know that exceptions propagate, right?

Comment: Suppose we have a delete query.There is always a possibility that the required tuple is not in the db.Also if we are trying to insert into a unique field, the element could already be present.Which means the db returns an error.Now if I have 10 of these statements & I have to print appropriate error messages for each of these means I have to use a separate try cache right. Am i missing anything ?

Comment: @Jibin Unless you want to continue onto the next statement after the first one fails, you don't need to wrap any of the statements in try..catch block. The exception will "break" the current execution "path" and "propragate" to wherever the next higher level try.catch is (in your scenario, you would have exactly one such try..catch block and it would "print appropriate error message").

Comment: BTW, the typical idiom for executing several interdependent SQL statements is this:: `using (DbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) { /* statements ... */ tran.Commit(); }` - exception skips the `Commit` and automatically rolls-back the transaction. There is no try..catch within that block.

Answer (score 3):

In ADO.NET, if a query fails due to an error then an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ADO.NET and the query failed you there will be an exception thrown. If not the query succeeded and you can check the result (that might still be empty if the query did not find any data fullfilling the request)